# Calculate the sum of $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{-N}^N 1/(n+e)$

Tags: calculus, summation, fourier-series, parsevals-identity

**Problem**

> Calculate the sum of $S = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{-N}^N 1/(n+e)$

**My attempt**

We quickly realize that $\frac{1}{e+n} + \frac{1}{e-n} = \frac{2e}{e^2-n^2} = \frac{-2e}{n^2+(ie)^2}$. Hence, the sum can be rewritten as:

$$ S = 1/e + \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{-2e}{n^2+(ie)^2} = 1/e - 2e \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2+(ie)^2}$$

We also know that the Fourier series of $e^{bx}$ on $(-\pi, \pi)$ is given by:

$$ e^{bx} = \frac{\sinh(b\pi)}{\pi} \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{(-1)^n}{b-in}e^{inx}$$

for $x \in(-\pi, \pi)$. By applying Parsevals formula we get:

$$ 2 \pi = \frac{\sinh^2(b\pi)}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{b^2+n^2} \cdot 2\pi $$

Which after rearranging gives us:

$$ \frac{\pi^2}{\sinh^2(b\pi)} = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{b^2+n^2} = 1/b^2 + 2\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{1}{b^2+n^2} $$

Plugging in $b = ie$ and utilizing the fact that $\sinh(ix) = i\sin(x)$ then gives us that:

$$2\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{1}{(ie)^2+n^2} =  \frac{\pi^2}{-\sin^2(\pi e)} + 1/e^2 $$

This can be substituted back into our sought sum $S$:

$$ S = 1/e - e \left( \frac{\pi^2}{-\sin^2(\pi e)} + 1/e^2 \right) = 1/e + \frac{e\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi e)} - 1/e = \frac{e\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi e)} $$

Which after calculating the original sum numerically is nowhere near the correct answer. What's going wrong here exactly?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying for.  That sum diverges, right?  Are you looking for an alternate summation method that might give a finite result?

Comment: @lulu Yes, maybe I should write $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{-N}^N 1/(n+e)$ instead. I have now edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense.  Still not obvious that that limit exists though...computations suggest that it is about $-2.57\cdots$

Comment: @lulu For $N = 10^8$ i get $-2.57051497199$. It seems to stay around approximately $-2.57$ even for larger $N$'s.

Comment: I agree with those numbers.

Comment: [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B1%2F%28n%5E2-exp%281%29%5E2%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+infinity%7D%5D) appears to give the correct value for your limit....same calculation you did, only I stayed with $n^2-e^2$ in the denominator.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, so $\pi \cot(\pi e)$ seems to be where I should land. However, I don't really see atm how I will be able to stay with $n^2-e^2$ in the denominator using my method since it involves taking the absolute values of the complex number in the denominator.

Comment: Check LHS of your result of "Parsevals formula", it should not be $2\pi$.

Comment: Use the polygamma function or generalized harmonic numbers. The asymptotic gives the result

Comment: @achillehui Thank you. I confused it for $e^{ibx}$ which in that case would give me $2\pi$. Thank you for realizing that error. I now managed to get the correct result :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for your comment, however, I'm not familiar with those concepts and wanted to try out solving it using Fourier series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{S} & \equiv\color{#44f}{\lim_{N \to \infty}\
\sum_{n\ =\ -N}^{N}\ {1 \over n + \expo{}}} =
\lim_{N \to \infty}\pars{%
\sum_{n\ =\ -N}^{-1}\ {1 \over n + \expo{}} + {1 \over \expo{}} + 
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{N}\ {1 \over n + \expo{}}}
\\[5mm] & = {1 \over \expo{}} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\pars{{1 \over n + \expo{}} + {1 \over -n + \expo{}}} =
{1 \over \expo{}} + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\pars{{1 \over n + 1 + \expo{}} - {1 \over n + 1 - \expo{}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \expo{}} +
\bracks{\Psi\pars{1 - \expo{}} - \Psi\pars{1 + \expo{}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \expo{}} +
\braces{\Psi\pars{1 - \expo{}} -
\overbrace{\bracks{\Psi\pars{\expo{}} + {1 \over \expo{}}}}^{\ds{Recursive\ Property}}}
\\[5mm] & = \Psi\pars{1 - \expo{}} - \Psi\pars{\expo{}} = \bbx{\color{#44f}{\pi\cot\pars{\pi\expo{}}}} \approx -2.5705\\ &
\end{align}
$\ds{\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function}$.